# Why is a list containing objects False when value tested?

Tags: python, object, truthtable

I would expect an empty list to value test as False, but I'm a bit confused why a reference for a list containing an object reports as False also when value tested as in the following example:

```
>>> weapon = []
>>> weapon == True
False
>>> weapon.append("sword")
>>> weapon == True
False
>>> weapon
['sword']
```

If `weapon = []` is False, why would `weapon = ['sword']` also be False? According to docs http://docs.python.org/release/2.4.4/lib/truth.html, it should be True. What am I missing in my understanding of this?

Comment: Because you're using `== True`.

Comment: But if `weapon = ['sword']` then should not weapon be True so `weapon == True`? Weapon is equaling an object as opposed to `None` or an empty string. The doc states "any empty sequence, for example, '', (), []." is considered False... ergo a non-empty string should == True.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `bool()` if you want to compare it directly

```
>>> weapon = []
>>> bool(weapon) == True
False
>>> weapon.append("sword")
>>> bool(weapon) == True
True
```

When you test a condition using `if` or `while`, the conversion to `bool` is done implicitly

```
>>> if weapon == True:  # weapon isn't equal to True
...     print "True"
... 
>>> if weapon:
...     print "True"
... 
True
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped. When I evaluate `weapon` via a defined function using a boolean it evaluate as True as long as it contains objects and False if empty.

Comment: @VinBreau, that's correct. The same type of thing works for empty string, empty tuples, empty dict, empty set, etc.

Answer (score 4):

you should do a check like

```
In [1]: w = []

In [2]: if w:
   ...:     print True
   ...: else:
   ...:     print False
   ...:
False
```

Answer (score 3):

When you do:

```
w = []
if w:
    print "Truthy"
else:
    print "Falsy"
```

the key thing to note is that whatever you are testing in the `if` clause is coerced to a boolean.  To make it explicit:

```
w = []
if bool(w):
    print "Truthy"
else:
    print "Falsy"
```

To compare apples to apples then you don't want to compare `["sword"]` to `True`.  Instead you want to compare `bool(["sword"])` to `True`:

```
bool(["sword"]) == True
# True
```

Answer (score 2):

From that article, note that even things are considered to have a "true" truth value, they are not necessarily `== True`. For example:

```
["hi"] == True 
// False

if ["hi"]:
    print("hello")
// prints hello
```

Answer (score 1):

The documentation says ***"Any object can be tested for truth value***" not that `[] == False` or `['whatever'] == True`. You should test objects as specified in the documentation ***"for use in an if or while condition or as operand of the Boolean operation"***.